# Unable to Manipulate Video time with Java Script

Tags: javascript

I m trying to add interactive content in a video while it's playing.

However, I kind of got a bit far but stuck at running a skip function upon clicking, forwarding the video time to a minute later.

To get a clear understanding, please take a look at my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body onload="onstart()"> 


<div id="stage" class="vid">
  <video class="vid" id="video" src="video.mp4" controls></video> 
</div>

<div id="one" style="background: black; height: 290px; width: 500px; position: absolute; top: 0px;display:none;">
    <img class="oneimage" src="images/danger.png" style="width: 150px; margin-left: 31%;margin-top: 5%;" />
    <h2 class="oneh" style="margin-left: 39%; margin-top: 3%;">WAIT..!</h2>
</div>

<div id="two" style="background: white; height: 290px; width: 500px; position: absolute; top: 0px; display: none;">
    <img class="oneimage" src="images/imwaiting.gif" style="width: 150px; margin-left: 31%; margin-top: 5%;" />
    <h2 class="twoh" style="margin-left: 32%; margin-top: 3%; color: black;">Are you 18+ ..?</h2>

    <button class="btn" onClick="skip()" style="background: red;margin-left: 20%;">No</button>
    <button class="btn" onclick="proceed()" style="background: #119a54;  margin-left: 30%;">Yes</button>
</div>

<div id="three" style="background: black; height: 290px; width: 500px; position: absolute; top: 0px;display:none;">
    <img class="oneimage" src="images/anyway.png" style="width: 150px; margin-left: 31%;margin-top: 5%;" />
    <h2 class="threeh" style="margin-left: 11%; margin-top: 3%;font-size:18px;color:white;">Then i m gonna have to skip the video to 1 min. LOL</h2>
</div>


<script>
  function onstart(){
    var v = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
    var t = document.getElementById('time');
    var skip = document.getElementById('skip');
    
    v.addEventListener('timeupdate',function(event){
    //   t.innerHTML = v.currentTime;

      if(v.currentTime > 5) {
        v.pause();
        document.getElementById("one").style.display = "block";
        
        setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementById("one").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("two").style.display = "block";
        }, 3000);
        
      } else { }
      
    },false);
  }
  
        function skip() {
            var v = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
            document.getElementById("two").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("three").style.display = "block";
            setTimeout(function(){
                document.getElementById("three").style.display = "none";
                v.play();
                v.pause();
                v.currentTime = 59;
                v.play();
            }, 3000);
        }
    
</script>

</body> 
</html>
```

It works fine till the display: none of class three div upon skip button. but doesn't skips the video to 59 secs as mentioned in the currenttime set.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thorough research (banging head on the table) on this, I finally got the solution I need.

Turns out all I need is to `remove the event listener timeupdate`

**so the final code goes as:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body > 

<style>
.vid {
    width:502px;
}
.btn {
    width: 50px; font-size: 15px; border: none; font-weight: 600; color: white;border-radius: 5px;
}
.oneimage {
    animation-duration: 20s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-iteration-count: once;
}
.oneimage{
    animation-name: anim-oneimage;
}
@keyframes anim-oneimage {
    0%, 8.3% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
  8.3%,25% { left: 25%; opacity: 1; }
}


.oneh {
    color: white; 
   -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
.oneh:hover { font-size: 2em; color: red; }
</style>

<div id="stage" class="vid">
  <video class="vid" id="video" src="video.mp4" controls></video> 
</div>

<div id="one" style="background: black; height: 289px; width: 502px; position: absolute; top: 0px;display:none;">
    <img class="oneimage" src="images/danger.png" style="width: 150px; margin-left: 31%;margin-top: 5%;" />
    <h2 class="oneh" style="margin-left: 39%; margin-top: 3%;">WAIT..!</h2>
</div>

<div id="two" style="background: white; height: 291px; width: 502px; position: absolute; top: 0px; display: none;">
    <img class="oneimage" src="images/imwaiting.gif" style="width: 150px; margin-left: 31%; margin-top: 5%;" />
    <h2 class="twoh" style="margin-left: 32%; margin-top: 3%; color: black;">Are you 18+ ..?</h2>

    <button class="btn" onClick="skip()" style="background: red;margin-left: 20%;">No</button>
    <button class="btn" onclick="proceed()" style="background: #119a54;  margin-left: 30%;">Yes</button>
</div>

<div id="three" style="background: black; height: 271px; width: 501px; position: absolute; top: 0px;display:none;">
    <img class="oneimage" src="images/anyway.png" style="width: 150px; margin-left: 31%;margin-top: 5%;" />
    <h2 class="threeh" style="margin-left: 11%; margin-top: 3%;font-size:18px;color:white;">Then i m gonna have to skip the video to 1 min. LOL</h2>
</div>

<div id="four" style="background: black; height: 289px; width: 502px; position: absolute; top: 0px;display:none;">
    <img class="oneimage" src="images/doubt.png" style="width: 150px; margin-left: 31%;margin-top: 5%;" />
    <h2 class="fourh" style="margin-left: 20%; margin-top: 3%;font-size:18px;color:white;">I Doubt it though. Any way Carry On</h2>
</div>


<script>

        function skip() {
                var vid = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
                document.getElementById("two").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("three").style.display = "block";
                setTimeout(function(){
                    document.getElementById("three").style.display = "none";
                    vid.currentTime = 59;
                    vid.play();
                }, 3000);
            }
        
        
        function proceed() {
            var vid = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
            document.getElementById("two").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("four").style.display = "block";
            setTimeout(function(){
                document.getElementById("four").style.display = "none";
                vid.play();
            }, 4000);
        }

        var pausing_function = function(){
            if(this.currentTime >= 5) {
                this.pause();
                document.getElementById("one").style.display = "block";
                
                setTimeout(function(){
                    document.getElementById("one").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("two").style.display = "block";
                }, 3000);
                
                // remove the event listener after you paused the playback
                this.removeEventListener("timeupdate",pausing_function);
            }
        };
        
        video.addEventListener("timeupdate", pausing_function);

</script>



</body> 
</html>
```

Hope it helps some one and save A LOT OF TIME..